# Set Text to textarea in UIWebView

Tags: xcode, dom, uiwebview

Im trying to set a Text to a textarea within an UIWebView.

```
<textarea class="GFS3D5JBNW" style="padding: 4px;border-radius: 5px;" placeholder="Some placeholder text ..." title="Some Title ..." tabindex="1"></textarea>
```

the code i´ve tried

```
NSString *source = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var inputFields = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'); \
                    for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { if(inputFields[i].tabindex == '1') inputFields[i].value = '%@';}", text];
[self.mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: source];
```

or

```
 NSString *source = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var inputFields = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea').value = '%@';}", text];
[self.mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: source];
```

but no success :-(  Has anyone a hint for me?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by

```
NSString *source = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var inputFields = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'); \
for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) {inputFields[i].value = '%@';}",input];
[self.mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:source];
```